# Is it possible in C/C++ in Linux to get informed when a specified date/time is reached?

Tags: c++, c, linux, timer

Is it possible using standard C++ in Linux to get informed when a specified date/time is reached by the system time (assuming my process is up of course)?

I could just set a timer to the time I need to wait, but what happens if the user changes the system time? Can I get informed by the system that the user changed the system time to reset my timers?

Comment: Yes, in recent kernels. It's a programming question, but it [was asked earlier on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/294984/how-to-make-an-application-detect-if-system-time-has-changed-in-linux)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Linux kernel has such system calls, although, they are not integrated into the libc API.
You can create a timer, get a file descriptor for it from the kernel, and do a select or epoll call on the descriptor to be notified when the timer fires.

The man page for it: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html

Comment: You can just specify an appropriate timeout to select/poll.

Comment: That's an interval timer (seconds since creation), not tied to day/time (seconds since midnight of a specified day0.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin The only appropriate timeout is one second. Any more than that and you fire late if the system time jumps forward.

Comment: Yes, the timerfd API does provide absolute timers (TFD_TIMER_ABSTIME). Also, library support is provided since glibc 2.8 (as stated on the linked man page), which was releases in 2009, so all current distros likely have timerfd support.

Comment: The timerfd method should work. Use `TFD_TIMER_ABSTIME` and `CLOCK_REALTIME`.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just write code to do exactly what you want. For example: You could keep a list of all such timers, the date/time they're supposed to be fired, and what code should be executed when they occur. Then every so often you could check the time to see if it's past the time any of your timers should fire. If so, fire them, remove them from the list, and go on about your business.

Comment: So not possible to get informed by the system? I have to check each second (I need 1 second resolution) if timer have expired?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to do it that way, but it's the easiest way. And the load it places on the system is less than .001%, so it's silly to try to optimize it.

Comment: It's an _apparent_ load. The fact that it's putting more stress on CPU cache means that a sloppily written application makes the whole system slower.

Comment: It's not "sloppily written", it's a considered design decision. Again, the load really is around .001%, and it makes the code considerably simpler and more portable. If you know a better solution, ...

Comment: I always try to avoid polling as a principle, anyway this is a possible solution. Also economically convenient as simple for me to develop.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for 'at' command (man at)

For example, at could send you an email at a given time, like 2:35 PM.

```
at 14:35
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> mail -s "It is 2:35 PM" dbadmin < /dev/null
at><EOT> # After CTRL/D pressed.
job 9 at Tue May  8 14:35:00 2012
```

Comment: How does this help a C/C++ program detect when this time has been reached?

Comment: you can specify the program name (exe) to get invoked at particular instance of time and in that executable you would be able to send the signal(or event) which can be handled/honored in your main c/c++ program.

Answer (score -1):

You can calculate the time from program start to the event, and call

```
sleep (difftime-1);
```

Then you could control if the time was reset, but this way you would only be able to correct the time to the future - if the time was set back, you would have skipped the event.

Comment: Ok, then point is if I can have a callback of the system time being reset by the user.

Comment: [A proposal](http://lwn.net/Articles/403004/) for reporting time changes to userspace has been bouncing around for a few years. The `sleep` method won't work -- it requires you to predict at `sleep` time what the offset between system time and monotonic time will be at wake time, which is in general not possible.

Comment: But the possibility, that the user resets the time after the alarm point has passed can't be avoided in general. I set an alarm at 12:00 for 16:00, and at 15:00 I set the clock to 17:00. That can't be avoided by observing the clock in intervals of seconds. I will the point though.